# Android Notification with Actions: Button displayed three times

Tags: android, notifications

I create a `Notification` using `NotificationCompat.Builder`. That notification gets an action button:

```
    notification = notificationBuilder
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.blabla)).
        .setContentText("")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.blabla)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntentOpenApp)
        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Cancel", pendingIntentAction)
        .build();
```

The notification displays, but the action is repeated three times:

[image]

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: Not much code so I'm just guessing: it looks like maybe you're using the same *notificationBuilder* three times, each time you add an action, so there are three of them

Comment: You are a genius... I never thought of that, but for some weird reason one of my colleagues or I have set up the NotificationBuilder as a Singleton...

Answer (score 0):

You can create notification by using following code:

```
var mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Description")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_notification,"OK",pendingIntent)
        .setChannelId(chanelId).build()


val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val mChanel = NotificationChannel(id, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChanel)
    notificationManager.notify(channelId, mBuilder)
}else{
    notificationManager.notify(channelId, mBuilder)
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but I didn't have any issue creating a notification per se